# jQuery element class not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I used to use the following syntax when using (previous versions of) jQuery:

`jQuery('<span/>', {className: 'a'};`

Using jQuery 1.6.2 the same will create `classname` attribute on the element and not `class`. So I tried using (the reserved word) `class` and it works, but only in (latest-ish) Chrome and Firefox. IE 7 will choke on the reserved word.

What am I missing here? The (truncated) script is below:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    className: 'wrap'
})
.append(jQuery('<div/>', {
    className: 'button',
    html: jQuery('<a/>', {
        href: function() {
            return '#'
        }(),
        className: 'amaranth',
        html: '<span>View in</span> Site'
    })
}))
.appendTo(that);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put quotes around the keyword `class`, which is more valid JSON anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.addClass()`:

```
jQuery('<div/>').addClass('test').appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/yCzgs/

Or add it inline:

```
jQuery('<div class="test2"/>').appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/yCzgs/1/